# Modification assembly (Dll) version without rebuilding using Ilmerge didn't work

Tags: ilmerge

I am trying to change the Dll version without rebuilding the code.

Reason: We are trying to change minor configurations in our server application this doesn't require any code changes in our client. We dont want take any risk in  rebuilding the code because there are no changes to the code.

So I was trying to update just the version of the Dll using Ilmerge.exe tool.

I ran the below command but I am not able to change the version of the output assembly file. I see same old version number in output dll.

Below is the command which I ran (copied from ilmerge commnad log output), I didn't get any kind of errors.

ILMerge version 2.12.803.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2004-2006. All rights reserved.
ILMerge C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SS_Logs\SS_Modify_Dll_Version\SS_Library.dll /lib:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies /lib:C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SS_Logs\SS_Modify_Dll_Version /keyfile:C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SS_Logs\SS_Modify_Dll_Version\SS_key.snk /target:library /targetplatform:v4,C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0 /out:C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SS_Logs\SS_Modify_Dll_Version\temp_SS.dll /ver:2.2.0.66 /ndebug /log:ilmerge_Log.txt

Comment: Am I missing any subcommand for changing the version of the assembly?

Comment: How are you checking the updated assembly's version?

Comment: I checked in file properties window. File and Product versions. I need to change these version numbers.

Comment: When I checked in ILDASM it shows updated version.

Comment: ILMerge only changes `AssemblyVersion`, it does not change `AssemblyFileVersion` which is shown in Explorer.

Comment: Is there any way to change the assembly file version?

Comment: Not out of the box. You can merge assembly attributes though, so inject a dll with the new attribute and version and figure out how the get merged in the output.